# wiremock soapXpath attribute

Tags: java, xml, stub, wiremock

I'm trying to get an xml attribute thoug soapXpath with wiremock but i can't doit, this is my SoapRequest.

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns2:Element>
                <ns2:InnerElement attribute="value"></ns2:InnerElement>
            </ns2:Element>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is how i'm trying to get the value of attribute.

```
    {{soapXPath request.body '/Element/InnerElement[@RatePlanCode]/text()'}}
```

response does not show errors, but it does not show the value, i can't figured out what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I keept trying and find the solution

```
{{soapXPath request.body '/Element/InnerElement/@attribute/'}}
```

with this i can get the attribute value